# Perform subtraction between two rows of the same group based on a rule via R

Tags: r, group-by, subtraction

I have a data frame where I have land use data for the year 2005 and 2018. I would like to generate a new data.frame that shows me the difference between 2005 and 2018 for each column, so that if there was a reduction, the minus sign(-). For example, if in 2005 the variable `Veg` had 1000 ha and in 2018 it had 8000 ha, the data.frame should indicate -200.

data.frame example:

`df`

> ```
> df<-structure(list(place = c("F01", "F01", "F02", "F02", "F03", "F03", 
> "F04", "F04", "F05", "F05", "F06", "F06"), year = c(2005, 2018, 
> 2005, 2018, 2005, 2018, 2005, 2018, 2005, 2018, 2005, 2018), 
>     Veg = c(12281.5824712026, 12292.2267477317, 7254.98919713131, 
>     7488.9138055415, 864.182200710528, 941.602680778032, 549.510775817472, 
>     584.104674537216, 5577.10195081334, 5688.28474549675, 1244.96456185886, 
>     1306.41862713264), Agri = c(113.178596532624, 1376.68748390712, 
>     85.2373706436, 1048.71071335262, 0, 46.236076173504, 0, 46.236076173504, 
>     85.2373706436, 1002.47463717912, 1.413692976528, 228.851945376768
>     ), Past = c(9190.16856517738, 7855.55923692456, 5029.33750161394, 
>     3776.9718412309, 983.015569149264, 800.981808818688, 710.255983089744, 
>     572.213021852304, 3726.66100294858, 2700.40306039963, 879.982298683488, 
>     597.410020198656), Urb = c(146.026168634304, 200.910719487744, 
>     146.026168634304, 200.910719487744, 141.119822421648, 194.840155529712, 
>     141.119822421648, 194.840155529712, 4.906346212656, 6.070563958032, 
>     NA, NA), SoloExp = c(61.12143163224, 67.940421283728, 61.12143163224, 
>     62.451966198384, 50.144521461552, 54.801392443056, 49.146620536944, 
>     52.639273773072, 9.895850835696, 7.650573755328, 6.320039189184, 
>     1.164217745376), Hidro = c(9.230583552624, 7.983207396864, 
>     9.230583552624, 7.983207396864, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.401098524176, 
>     6.320039189184, 5.654771906112, 4.490554160736), total = c(691953.981181971, 
>     691953.981181971, 691953.981181971, 691953.981181971, 691953.981181971, 
>     691953.981181971, 691953.981181971, 691953.981181971, 691953.981181971, 
>     691953.981181971, 691953.981181971, 691953.981181971)), row.names = c(NA, 
> -12L), class = "data.frame")
> ```

I would like to get an output like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this by using `across` function:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(place, year), ~ lag(., default = .[1]) - .)) %>% 
  filter(year==2018) %>% 
  select(-year)
```

```
  place        Veg        Agri      Past        Urb   SoloExp    Hidro total
1   F01  -10.64428 -1263.50889 1334.6093 -54.884551 -6.818990 1.247376     0
2   F02 -233.92461  -963.47334 1252.3657 -54.884551 -1.330535 1.247376     0
3   F03  -77.42048   -46.23608  182.0338 -53.720333 -4.656871       NA     0
4   F04  -34.59390   -46.23608  138.0430 -53.720333 -3.492653       NA     0
5   F05 -111.18279  -917.23727 1026.2579  -1.164218  2.245277 1.081059     0
6   F06  -61.45407  -227.43825  282.5723         NA  5.155821 1.164218     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr pipe that is robust to the order of rows (e.g., if `2005` ever occurs *after* `2018` for whatever reason).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c("place", "year")) %>%
  pivot_wider(c("place", "name"), names_from = "year", values_from = "value") %>%
  mutate(results = coalesce(`2005` - `2018`, 0)) %>%
  transmute(place, name, results = dplyr::coalesce(results, 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(place, names_from = "name", values_from = "results")
# # A tibble: 6 x 8
#   place    Veg    Agri  Past    Urb SoloExp Hidro total
#   <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 F01    -10.6 -1264.  1335. -54.9    -6.82  1.25     0
# 2 F02   -234.   -963.  1252. -54.9    -1.33  1.25     0
# 3 F03    -77.4   -46.2  182. -53.7    -4.66  0        0
# 4 F04    -34.6   -46.2  138. -53.7    -3.49  0        0
# 5 F05   -111.   -917.  1026.  -1.16    2.25  1.08     0
# 6 F06    -61.5  -227.   283.   0       5.16  1.16     0
```